# Hiding JLabels and JTextFields depending on object's status

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hi i am coding  a program and i only want my ID field to be visible when updating so when status == 
but when satus ==0 its adding and i want the label and text ffield hidden i have tried using .Setvisible(false ) but it is not working

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String Fname = txtFirstName.getText();
    String Surname = txtSurname.getText();
    String Email = txtEmail.getText();
    String ContactNo = txtContact.getText();

    if ( status == 0) { 
        lblID.setVisible(false);
        txtID.setVisible(false);
        list.addTenant(Fname, Surname, Email, ContactNo);
        new TenantView().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    } else {
        lblID.setVisible(true);
        txtID.setVisible(true);
        TenantList ten = new TenantList();
        list.updateTenant(Fname, Surname, Email, ContactNo,  TenantView.selectedTenant.getID());
        new TenantView().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: A valid [mre] code post would help quite a bit. Note that when changing the visibility of your components, you usually should call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container (usually a JPanel) that holds these components. Also note that CardLayouts are often used for this purpose. Also what may be wrong is *when* and *where* you change the visibility, and maybe this ActionListener is not the place to do it.

Comment: hi whats a cardlayout

Comment: Google Swing CardLayout Tutorial, probably the first hit

Comment: i figured it out you can set visibility in the initcomponents()  with if statments

Comment: thank you for your help